# OpenGL rendering to a QML item

Tags: qt, qml, qglwidget, qtdeclarative

I have a QML file which contains a layout of QML items and now I want one of those items to be a QGLWidget. i.e. I want to render to a specific QML item.

Is anyone aware of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I suppose it to provide QML a new custom component implemented in C++. I couldn't find anything ready.

You could subclass the QDeclarativeItem and implement your OpenGL code in the paint function after using the [QPainter::beginNative()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qpainter.html#beginNativePainting) function. After that you can "export" your new custom item to QML [this way](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html#defining-new-qml-elements). This is quite simple and should work, but you'll have to setup the viewport of you QDeclarativeView to be a QGLWidget, something like this:

```
QDeclarativeView view;
// This is needed because OpenGL viewport doesn't support partial updates.
view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdateMode);
view.setViewport(new QGLWidget);
```

or you'll have to use the opengl graphics system for the entire application.
Another way is using [QML/3D](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt3d-1.0/qt3d-qml3d.html).

[This thread](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/4109) will give you some other information.